# Is there anything special about 2017-12-02T12:15

Tags: ios, time, timezone, epoch

There is a news story today that time-based local notifications on iPhones are causing them to reboot once the time passes 12:15 on the 2nd of December in their local timezone, but nowhere is offering any reason why this might be the case.

I'm curious why this date is special. I'm aware of several rollover dates (The famous Y2K bug for dates stored in YY format, the 2038 bug for 32-bit rollover in unix timestamps, and similar) but nothing like that seems to apply here. I also know that various OSes have struggled with daylight savings time changes & timezone updates over the years, but that doesn't seem to apply here either.

In Unix format, that time is 1512216900 / 1512216900000, neither of which are near to big round numbers in binary.

Is there anything special about 2017-12-02T12:15 in any standard date formats? Or is this more likely to be due to some obscure internal date representation / parsing the OS is using?

Comment: Interesting that seems like this bug is only for US. So may be it relative to imperial system

Comment: @nerowolfe - What makes you think the bug is only for the US?

Comment: because here in Russia there was no such bug

Comment: @nerowolfe the first reports were from Australia, so unlikely to be just U.S., but could still be country-related. Also I've never come across any imperial vs. metric split for time! I think seconds are the same the world over.